# Python barplot from Counter

Tags: python, seaborn, counter

I am brand new to Python and I am starting a BS in data analytics in August I am trying to get a head start on learning. Can anyone solve this for me?

```
from collections import Counter
Counter(one_d)
```

returns the following

```
Counter({'Action': 303,
         'Adventure': 259,
         'Sci-Fi': 120,
         'Mystery': 106,
         'Horror': 119,
         'Thriller': 195,
         'Animation': 49,
         'Comedy': 279,
         'Family': 51,
         'Fantasy': 101,
         'Drama': 513,
         'Music': 16,
         'Biography': 81,
         'Romance': 141,
         'History': 29,
         'Crime': 150,
         'Western': 7,
         'War': 13,
         'Musical': 5,
         'Sport': 18})
```

I would like to create a Barplot but am unsure how to do this. Is barplot even the best choice for this data?

Answer (score 0):

The [Pandas library](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/10min.html) is quite useful for data analytics and visualization:

```py
from collections import Counter

import pandas as pd


counts = Counter({'Action': 303, 'Adventure': 259, 'Sci-Fi': 120, 'Mystery': 106, 'Horror': 119, 'Thriller': 195, 'Animation': 49, 'Comedy': 279, 'Family': 51, 'Fantasy': 101, 'Drama': 513, 'Music': 16, 'Biography': 81, 'Romance': 141, 'History': 29, 'Crime': 150, 'Western': 7, 'War': 13, 'Musical': 5, 'Sport': 18})
data = pd.Series(counts)
ax = data.plot.bar()
ax.set(xlabel='Genre', ylabel='Count', title='Good luck on your BS')
```

[image]